# Conditional Class Import

Tags: java, android, import

I'm trying to build an app with backwards compatibility, but I'm still using some classes that are only available in newer SDK versions by checking the `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`.

However, I still need to import those classes into my project and that is giving me an error when running on older devices. Can I conditionally import classes in android? I've tried looking for something on Google, but I probably don't know what to search to return valid results.

tl;dr - I want to use classes added in newer API/SDK versions on older devices, but the `import newer.api.level.class` is preventing my application from working. What do I do?

EDIT: Specifically to me, I am implementing the PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener protocol in one of my activities and that is what the application is complaining about.

The error is `Failed resolving Lcom/example/myApp; interface 575 'Landroid/widget/PopupMenu$OnMenuItemClickListener;'`

Comment: Preventing from *working* or *compiling*? Very different. Also, you'll want to read this: ["Android targeting system"](http://codeisland.org/2012/android-targeting-system/)

Comment: @LukasKnuth I would have guessed working, since the application compiles, but it won't run on the older devices.

Comment: @LukasKnuth I have updated my question to include the specific issue.

Comment: Read the post. You'll need to compile with the newest Android SDK version available and specify `minSdkVersion` to get it working under older devices.

Comment: @LukasKnuth I have that already. Its not a compile issue. Its runtime.

Comment: You ensured that none of the "new API"-code runs on the older devices? Also post the full StackTrace.

Comment: @LukasKnuth Can you please read my edit? I need to conditionally handle my `implements` protocol.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24938/discussion-between-lukas-knuth-and-rileye)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here was not the `import` (which should be handled at compile-time), but the fact that the Activity (which was used on every platform) implemented the `PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener`, which caused the problem with devices running older platforms.

When using new API features, always make sure that **all** usage of new classes/methods is **only** executed on devices with fitting API Levels, through [Conditional Execution](http://codeisland.org/2012/android-targeting-system/#conditional-execution).

The correct way here is to not make the Activity implement the listener, but to make the listener an anonymous class in the conditional-execution block, similar to how it's being done [here](https://github.com/LukasKnuth/bike-track/blob/3b60c31d85c2f9f45dbd70be30ada944a85dc5a8/src/org/knuth/biketrack/Main.java#L138).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the detail, you may want to look the below which focuses on backward compatibility;

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Comment: I've edited my question. Specifically, I'm referring to PopupMenu. However, I'm sure I will encounter other components that are not in the support-library as well.